# How to clean water softer salt tank without disconnecting?

Tags: water-softener

About 6mo ago, I replaced my 20+yo water softener with a Morton M34 model (resin tank inside salt tank).

When I disconnected the old one, I put all the salt from it in a box in my laundry room instead of disposing it.  Well, a couple weeks ago I had the brilliant idea to reuse that old salt (bad idea).  Now there is 6+in of "salt silt" in the bottom of the tank plus lots of brown floaties in the water.

I've let the salt level go down to as far as it will go on it's own and I would like to clean the rest of the "silt" out and start fresh but I can't reach the bottom of the tank to get it out.

I would prefer to not have to disconnect it and tip onto it's side if at all possible.

Ideas?

Comment: What about triggering several regeneration cycles. This may flush some of the material out. After that a wet vacuum to suck everything that is left.

Comment: @EdBeal Wet/Dry vac is a good idea.  I had been thinking I would go buy a fish tank sifon (sp?) but that it might not have enough suction due to not having much verticle drop to pull the water so I never tried it.  Completely forgot that I have a 16g shop vac in the garage (never use it for wet cleanup so I didn't think about it).  You should post that as an answer.  Even if it doesn't end up working for me, I'm sure it would work for someone at a later date.  Regen cycles is a good idea too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try triggering several regeneration cycles. This may flush some of the material out. After that a wet vacuum to suck everything that is left. Added as an answer.

Comment: If you just keep doing regen cycles, it will eventually use all the salt and there will be nothing in there but ever weakening brine.  In the meantime, use a wet-dry vac to get any crud you can reach.

Comment: Some salt has other minerals that are not water soluble. These end up on the bottom of the tank and needs to be cleaned out every few years because the rock salt is never 5 9's or 99.999 % pure.

Comment: This worked like a charm.  Wet vac to the rescue.  I did run 4 regens over the last 24hrs as well.  There was still about 4 inches of filth in the bottom.  Now I just have to figure out where to clean out my shop vac since I really don't want to salt my lawn.

Comment: I doubt there is much salt left. On a gravel road Down the center may be 1 option, another on fence lines where you don't want things to grow would be another. A + would be appreciated since my answer helped.